# ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1.5"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, int

I'm trying to execute the following code to see if I related the tables of my model correctly:

```
drop table if exists ImportA;
create table ImportA (

    id varchar(255),
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    street varchar(255),
    neighbourhood varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    zipcode varchar(255),
    country_code varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    property_type varchar(255),
    accommodates varchar(255),
    bathrooms varchar(255),
    bedrooms varchar(255),
    beds varchar(255),
    amenities text,
    square_feet varchar(255),
    price varchar(255),
    weekly_price varchar(255),
    monthly_price varchar(255),
    security_deposit varchar(255),
    cleaning_fee varchar(255),
    minimum_nights varchar(255),
    maximum_nights varchar(255)
);

drop table if exists ImportH;
create table ImportH (

    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    host_id  varchar(255),
    host_url varchar(255),
    host_name varchar(255),
    host_since varchar(255),
    host_about text,
    host_response_time varchar(255),
    host_response_rate varchar(255),
    host_is_superhost varchar(255),
    host_picture_url varchar(255),
    host_listings_count varchar(255),
    host_verifications varchar(255),
    host_identity_verified varchar(255)
);

drop table if exists ImportR;
create table ImportR (

    id varchar(255),
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    street varchar(255),
    neighbourhood varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    date_review varchar(255),
    reviewer_id varchar(255),
    reviewer_name varchar(255),
    comments text
);

copy ImportA from '/Users/Shared/BDD/apartments.csv' csv header delimiter ',';
copy ImportH from '/Users/Shared/BDD/hosts.csv' csv header delimiter ',';
copy ImportR from '/Users/Shared/BDD/review.csv' csv header delimiter ',';

drop table if exists Country cascade;
create table Country (

    country_code varchar(255),
    country varchar(255),
    primary key (country_code)
);

drop table if exists Payment cascade;
create table Payment (

    id_payment serial,
    price money,
    weekly_price money,
    monthly_price money,
    security_deposit money,
    cleaning_fee money,
    primary key (id_payment)
);

drop table if exists Characteristic cascade;
create table Characteristic (

    id_characteristic serial,
    property_type varchar(255),
    accommodates int,
    bathrooms int,
    bedrooms int,
    beds int,
    square_feet int,
    minimum_nights int,
    maximum_nights int,
    primary key (id_characteristic)
);

drop table if exists Host cascade;
create table Host (

    host_id int,
    host_url varchar(255),
    host_name varchar(255),
    host_since date,
    host_about text,
    host_response_time varchar(255),
    host_response_rate varchar(255),
    host_is_superhost boolean,
    host_picture_url varchar(255),
    host_listings_count int,
    host_identity_verified boolean,
    primary key (host_id)
);

drop table if exists Media cascade;
create table Media (

    id_verification serial,
    media varchar(255),
    primary key (id_verification)
);

drop table if exists RelationHostMedia cascade;
create table RelationHostMedia (

    host_id int,
    id_verification int,
    primary key (host_id, id_verification),
    foreign key (host_id) references Host (host_id),
    foreign key (id_verification) references Media (id_verification)
);

drop table if exists Amenitie cascade;
create table Amenitie (

    id_amenitie serial,
    id_characteristic int,
    amenitie varchar(255),
    primary key (id_amenitie),
    foreign key (id_characteristic) references Characteristic (id_characteristic)
);

drop table if exists Place cascade;
create table Place (

    id_place serial,
    street varchar(255),
    neighbourhood varchar(255),
    city varchar(255),
    state varchar(255),
    zipcode varchar(255),
    country_code varchar(255),
    primary key (id_place),
    foreign key (country_code) references Country (country_code)
);

drop table if exists Apartment cascade;
create table Apartment (

    id_apartment int,
    url varchar(255),
    name varchar(255),
    description text,
    picture_url varchar(255),
    id_place int,
    id_payment int,
    id_characteristic int,
    host_id int,
    primary key (id_apartment),
    foreign key (id_place) references Place (id_place),
    foreign key (id_payment) references Payment (id_payment),
    foreign key (id_characteristic) references Characteristic (id_characteristic),
    foreign key (host_id) references Host (host_id)
);

drop table if exists Reviewer cascade;
create table Reviewer (

    reviewer_id int,
    reviewer_name varchar(255),
    primary key (reviewer_id)
);

drop table if exists Review cascade;
create table Review (

    id_review serial,
    reviewer_id int,
    id_apartment int,
    date_review date,
    comments text,
    primary key (id_review),
    foreign key (reviewer_id) references Reviewer (reviewer_id),
    foreign key (id_apartment) references Apartment (id_apartment)
);

insert into Country (country_code, country)
select distinct country_code, country
from ImportA;

insert into Payment (price, weekly_price, monthly_price, security_deposit, cleaning_fee)
select cast(price as money), cast(weekly_price as money), cast(monthly_price as money), cast(security_deposit as money), cast(cleaning_fee as money)
from ImportA;

insert into Characteristic (property_type, accommodates, bathrooms, bedrooms, beds, square_feet, minimum_nights, maximum_nights)
select property_type, cast(accommodates as int), cast(bathrooms as int), cast(bedrooms as int), cast(beds as int), cast(square_feet as int), cast(minimum_nights as int), cast(maximum_nights as int)
from ImportA;

insert into Host (host_id, host_url, host_name, host_since, host_about, host_response_time, host_response_rate, host_is_superhost, host_picture_url, host_listings_count, host_identity_verified)
select cast(host_id as int), host_url, host_name, cast(host_since as date), cast(host_about as text), host_response_time, host_response_rate, cast(host_is_superhost as boolean), host_picture_url, cast(host_listings_count as int), cast(host_identity_verified as boolean)
from ImportH;

insert into Media (media)
select host_verifications
from ImportH;

insert into RelationHostMedia (host_id, id_verification)
select distinct host_id, id_verification
from Host, Media;

insert into Amenitie (id_characteristic, amenitie)
select id_characteristic, amenities
from Characteristic, ImportA;

insert into Place (street, neighbourhood, city, state, zipcode, country_code)
select street, neighbourhood, city, state, zipcode, country_code
from ImportA, Country;

insert into Apartment (id_apartment, url, name, description, picture_url, id_place, id_payment, id_characteristic, host_id)
select cast(id_apartment as int), url, name, cast(description as text), picture_url, id_place, id_payment, id_characteristic, host_idfrom ImportA, Place, Payment, Characteristic, Host;

select id_place from Apartment;
```

This code are just the creation of the Import tables and main tables and also the insertion of data into each table, relating them. Also, I'm not 100% sure this relations are coded fine, I was trying to figure it out by debugging it but the output when I execute it is:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1.5"

What does this mean? I have checked all my integer atributes and they seem fine nor I have no atribute called "1,5".

Comment: Check the number formats in your csv files

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you are trying to insert the value `1.5` into an integer field.

`1.5` is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify please if this query (used to feed Characteric table) works fine :

```
  Select property_type, cast(accommodates as int), cast(bathrooms as int), cast(bedrooms as int), cast(beds as int), cast(square_feet as int), cast(minimum_nights as int), cast(maximum_nights as int) from ImportA;
```

Otherwise, you will have to check all the requests in which you are trying to do (cast field integer) to detect the problem of transforming this decimal value (1.5) into an integer.